# must capture document properties for word, excel and powerpoint documents

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, ms-office

I am new to VBA and this area. I would like to capture the document proporties like (document title, subject, author, team, manager,company etc...) while create or saving the document. This properties capture is must and i would like to implement to all the Word, Excel, Powerpoint users in my company. 
   How this can be possible. If I wrote a macro, is it possible to deploy all the MS-Office users. or a VB program will do?. 
    All i need is to make mandatory to input document properties for all the documents. these properties can also be fetched from a template file from the user machine. 
    Is this possible in VBA or any other easy ways to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to (a) force your users to enter the properties, or (b) just get the properties from the documents?

Comment: it's option (a). Everyone must enter the document properties to save a new document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force users to fill in all the properties before saving the document, you can create add-ins (one for each of Excel, Word and PowerPoint) that [intercept the "before save" event](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InterceptSavePrintContent.htm) and check the document properties. If the add-in detects some properties that have not been filled in, it can prompt the user and cancel the save.

The means by which you can create an add-in is similar (but not identical) across the 3 applications. You would of course also have to ensure that the add-ins were installed on all your users machines.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I just got how to create add-in for MS-Office. will try and post my results.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to be able to read (or modify) the properties, you can use the [Office Document Property Reader](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=224351) to read *and write* properties of Office documents, without even needing Office installed. That works across all Office applications.